# How to map data depending on whether I ever get different objects? JS Angular 2+

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to filter through, but the problem is that the knowledge I get changes its properties

First example of object ( of arrays )

```
{ name : 'test' , value: 'Values 1' },
{ name :'test 2' , value: 'Values 2' }
```

And when i filter this is easy:

```
  <span *ngFor="let date of dates">
   {{ date.value  }}
  </span>
```

But second time i got different data

```
{ name : 'test' , value: 'Values 1' },
{ name :'test 2' , value: 'Values 2' }
{ name :'test 3' , value: [{name :'test 3' , value: 'Values 3'}] },
{ name :'test 4' , value: [{name :'test 4' , value: 'Values 4'}] }
```

I need to filter this data and show only value ( last value )

the menu is currently displayed result example:

> Values 1 , Values 2, [Object Object] ,  [Object Object]

Answer (score 0):

You can use map to modify the array of objects as per your need.

```
dates.map(x=>{
        if(Array.isArray(x.value))
           x.value = x.value[0].value
        return x;
        });
```

The result will be

```
[{ name : 'test' , value: 'Values 1' },
{ name :'test 2' , value: 'Values 2' }
{ name :'test 3' , value: 'Values 3'},
{ name :'test 4' , value: 'Values 4' }]
```

Update: if you want to print all the values, you can join them using map function, this will work for `n` objects inside `value` array.

```
dates.map(filerVal => {
      if (Array.isArray(filerVal.value)){       
        filerVal.value = filerVal.value.map(v=>v.value).join(' ');
      }       
      return filerVal;
    });
```

[stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-expample-5bnjn1?file=src/app/app.component.ts).
let me know if this is what you expect.

Comment: this works half because if the same json with 2 objects arrives. You only take the first one
 filerVal.value[0].value

Comment: Could you please be more clear on your ask? Please try to add your initial array of objects with scenarios and expected output. What needs to be done if you got more than one objects in the values?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-expample?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: In stackblitz is all demonstration with your code @Annamalai

Comment: Check second json. Have 2 object but only first is printed..

Comment: Are you sure that you will get maximum two objects? And if not how would you want to handle such value. Do you just want to concatenate the value strings from all objects? Please provide the expected output in such scenarios.

Comment: I want only to print that data.... Yes i am sure, anytime will be more then 3 or 4 items..

Comment: Array.reduce method can help for n number of objects in array

Answer (score 0):

You could NgIf and check if date.value is typeof array, if yes and its only 1 object, then make it display {{date.value.value}} else if its not an array display {{date.value}} ... sorry I can't type specifics